# Как сделать задержку цикла без корутин?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пришлось избавиться от корутин, так-как выяснилось, что `WaitForSeconds` и другие на мобилах работают только при значениях `0.1f` и выше, или `null`, что будет также как и `0.1f`, а нужно быстрее, то есть `0.01f`, к примеру, и сколько я не пытался, ничего не вышло.

Задача стоит сделать свой таймер, на любое значение по времени, вне функции `Update`, ибо этот метод не используется, так как завязка происходит на кнопке `UI` при нажатии на которую вызывается метод.

Но сколько я не пытался искать, ничего не удалось найти по таймеру, везде про корутины пишут.

Попытался написать метод:

```
public static float timer;
public static bool Wait(float seconds) {
    float timerMax = seconds;
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    return timer >= timerMax;
}
```

А после использовать его в цикле:

```
private void OnStart() {
    while (true) {
        if (Wait(0.01f)) {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Результат не дало, сколько бы я не ставил в `Wait(22f);`, всё срабатывает мгновенно, без задержки.

Тут я понял, что `Time.deltaTime` возвращает одно и тоже значение и не меняется и служит для работы `Update` метода.

Пытался также сделать и через `Time.time` но и этот метод постоянно возвращает одно и тоже значение.

И вот тут то я встал в ступор, как же правильно сделать таймер, который будет задерживать цикл, на нужное количество секунд?

Comment: У вас за один кадр весь `while` прогоняется. Вот и всё. Хотите оперировать маленькими периодами, создайте отдельный поток и с ним таймер синхронизируйте.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, похоже, что вы правы, а как мне это сделать? Что-то не догоняю.

Comment: А зачем вам нужны таймеры с такой точностью?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Для раскрутки, колеса.

Comment: Странно, `Time.deltaTime` должен возвращать валидное значение. Вы уверены, что оно у вас неверное?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ну оно одно и тоже возвращает в консоль, к примеру вывожу, через этот метод, он `1000+` раз одно и тоже значение пишет и больше ничего. С `Time.time` таже беда, только меньше чем `1000` =) Но може это потому что с `Update` не работаю?

Comment: Вообще Time.deltaTime не должен зависеть от апдейта. Подозреваю, что у вас стоит вертикальная синхронизация и в консоль выводится число 1/60 или 1/30, что у вас в консоли выводится?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, да синхронизация стоит, выводит просто там, что-то `0.0235458.....` (много циферок). Но я похоже разобрался `InvokeRepeating("l", 0.01f, 0.01f);` - пока работает как надо, просто когда достигнуто нужное число, делаю `CancelInvoke()`, не знаю, конечно, как это себя на мобилах поведет, завтра буду тестить.

Comment: Это примерно 40фпс, что странно, обычно вертикалка сбрасывает частоты до 30 в таком случае. `InvokeRepeating` как вариант, работает, однако лучше туда передавать не имя метода, а сам метод, так быстрее. Да и это немного костыльно. По-хорошему, нужно разобраться с `deltaTime`, я уверен, что что-то мы упускаем из виду :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, на сколько знаю, у вертикалки, 2 режима 60-120 фпс, 30-40 фпс. у меня стоит 60-120 и редакторе показывает 80 - 100. В `InvokeRepeating` - можно передать только название метода. Ко всему это будет единственная разовая операция за всю игру, только в начале для раскрутки, а дальше уже остановок никогда не будет. Просто бесило, что очень медленно раскручивалось, теперь шустрит. Но всеже потестирую, если будут какие мысли по поводу `deltaTime`, пишите =) Хочется тоже понять, что за дела такие.

Comment: Действительно, всегда думал, что у InvokeRepeating есть перегрузка под метод. Если 1 раз, тогда не страшно.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без корутины...

```
private float _timer;

private void Update () {
    _timer += Time.deltaTime;
    while (_timer >= 0.1f) {
        _timer -= 0.1f;
        Step();
    }
}

private void TimeStep () {
    // Каждые 0.1 сек
}
```

Только я вообще не понял зачем нужен ровный временной шаг для раскрутки колеса...

Почему бы просто не

```
private void Update () {
    WheelRotationSpeed += Time.deltaTime*Accelerate;
}
```

Не одеваете ли вы штаны через голову?

Comment: Вопрос читали? Видимо нет...

Comment: Я не понял, почему `UI` кнопка делает `Update` не кошерным...

Comment: Потому что, во первых, вы ее потом не остановите, во вторых. нужно. чтобы работало в одном месте и в третьих. мне это не нравится. Ферштейн? =) Нужно читать вопрос просто внимательно, а не тулить свое. Решение найдено, по этому можете это удалить.